# Using the Mean Value Theorem, show that if $f'(x) > 0$ $\forall x \in (a, b)$ then $f$ is increasing on $(a, b)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, proof-verification

Using the Mean Value Theorem, show that if $f'(x) > 0$ $\forall x \in (a, b)$ then $f$ is increasing on $(a, b)$.

---

The Mean Value Theorem states: a function $f$ which is continuous on the closed interval $[a, b] $ $^{\textbf{(1)}}$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$ $^\textbf{(2)}$ has at least one value $c: a < c < b$ where $f'(c) = \dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$.

Set $f(x)$ to be some function such that $f'(x) > 0$ $\forall x \in (a, b) \implies f(x)$ is continuous $\forall x \in [a, b]$ $^\textbf{(1)}$ and differentiable $\forall x \in (a, b)$ $^{\textbf{(2)}}$. Hence, $\exists c: f'(c) = \dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} \implies f'(c)(b - a) + f(a) = f(b) \implies f(b) > f(a) \therefore f$ is increasing on $(a, b)$.

---

Is this proof sufficient?

Comment: No, of course not. All you did is to show that $\;f(b)>f(a)\;$ ...what happens in between?! The function could be up and down in the middle and still fulfill what you showed. What you have to do is to take $\;a\le x<y\le b\;$ and then prove that $\;f(x)<f(y)\;$ ...which is almost identical with what you did.

Comment: instead, pick any two points $c, d$ in $(a, b)$ such that $c<d.$ apply the mean value theorem on $(c,d)$ like you did on $(a,b).$ conclude $f(c) < f(d).$  since for $c,d$ were arbitrary, you have $f(c) < f(d)$  that proves $f$ is increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of your proof is right but you need to modify the argument because what you have shown is that $f(a) < f(b)$ and what you need to show is that $f(x) < f(y)$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$ whenever $x<y$. So, choose any $x,y \in [a,b]$ with $x < y$ and now applying your idea of the proof to the interval $[x,y]$ you will get $f(y) > f(x)$ and this will prove that $f$ is increasing.

Answer (score 3):

No, your proof only proves that $f(b)>f(a)$. for example, the function $$f(x)=x^2$$ on the interval $(-1,2)$ also satisfies the condition that $f(2)>f(1)$, but $f$ is clearly not increasing at all points.

You need to prove that, for any pair $x,y\in(a,b)$, if $x<y$, then $f(x)<f(y)$.