# $x + \epsilon f(x)$ is injective when $\epsilon$ is small

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and if $|f '(t)| \le M$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$, then
there exists $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for all $0 < \epsilon \le \epsilon_0$ , the function

$$g(x) = x + \epsilon f (x)$$

is injective.

Comment: This fact will be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212756/using-the-mean-value-theorem-show-that-if-fx-0-forall-x-in-a-b-th

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Find an $\epsilon$ such that $g'(x) > 0$.

Comment: $g'(x)=1+\epsilon f'(x)>0 \implies f'(x)>-\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

Comment: What can we conclude from this?

Comment: @Unknownx we can guarantee that $1 + \epsilon f'(x)$ will be greater than zero if we choose an $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon < 1/M$